# Android aar classDefNotFound because of GSON dependency

Tags: android, gson, android-library, aar

When I try use an exported android library project (aar format) in other project. I get the following errors.

```
> "Could not find class 'com.manish.core.helper.RegistrationHelper$1'" 
> "Could not find class 'com.manish.core.helper.RegistrationHelper$2'"
> "Could not find class 'com.manish.core.helper.RegistrationHelper$3'"
> "Could not find class 'com.manish.core.helper.RegistrationHelper$4'"
```

It is failing at when control hits

```
Type finalType = new TypeToken<GenericResponse<Response>>() {}.getType();
```

I think I am getting this error because the constructor TypeToken is protected `protected TypeToken(){}`, so we can't access it inside aar(as we can access only public class and member in aar).

can someone please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where RegistrationHelper is located?

Comment: Then there must be a method inside the same class which will be public and will be returning "TypeToken(){}"

Comment: @KishuDroid It is inside the aar file.

Comment: Are you using proguard on the aar file?